# How to change value of LiveData and not notify the observers

Tags: android, android-livedata

In some cases, I want to change the value of LiveData and don't want the observers to notify about the change. How can I do that?

Comment: You should always expect to notify the observers, that's the point of the observer pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think my custom class will help you

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.support.annotation.MainThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Pair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SSBLiveData<T> extends MutableLiveData<T> {

    private List<Pair<LifecycleOwner, Observer>> observers = new ArrayList<>();

    @MainThread
    @Override
    public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull final Observer observer) {
        observers.add(new Pair<>(owner, observer));
        super.observe(owner, observer);
    }

    @MainThread
    private void resetAllObservers() {
        for (Pair<LifecycleOwner, Observer> observer : observers) {
            super.observe(observer.first, observer.second);
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    private void removeAllObservers() {
        for (Pair<LifecycleOwner, Observer> observer : observers) {
            removeObservers(observer.first);
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    void setValueWithoutNotify(T value) {
        removeAllObservers();
        super.setValue(value);
        System.out.println("Not notifying value " + getValue());
    }
   // For androidx use this method
   /*@MainThread
   @Override
   public void removeObserver(@NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) {
    for (Pair<LifecycleOwner, Observer> observerItem : observers) {
        if (observerItem.second.equals(observer) && observerItem.first.getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
            observers.remove(observerItem);
        }
    }
    super.removeObserver(observer);
   }*/

    @MainThread
    @Override
    public void removeObserver(@NonNull Observer<T> observer) {
        for (Pair<LifecycleOwner, Observer> observerItem : observers) {
            if (observerItem.second.equals(observer) && observerItem.first.getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
                observers.remove(observerItem);
            }
        }
        super.removeObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(T value) {
        super.setValue(value);
        if (!hasObservers()) {
            resetAllObservers();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it this way

```
SSBLiveData<String> liveData = new SSBLiveData<>();
liveData.setValueWithoutNotify("It won't get notified");
liveData.setValue("It will get notified");
```

Comment: I am getting error: 'removeObserver(Observer<T>)' in 'com.behkameh.daggersample.util.SSBLiveData' clashes with 'removeObserver(Observer<? super T>)' in 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Comment: That's because you are using androidx and there are certain changes in live data of androidx library, I have edited my answer and added removeObserver method for androidx kindly check my edited answer

Answer (score 11):

I would just use `Pair<T, Boolean>` as the value type, and the observers can check `pair.second`

The idea is simple. Replace your `MutableLiveData<String>` with `MutableLiveData<Pair<String, Boolean>>`

When you want to notify the observers with value `s`, just call `liveData.setValue(new Pair(s, true))` and call `liveData.setValue(new Pair(s, false))` otherwise

on the observer side, just check the `pair.second` to distinguish these two cases

Edit: I was using phone to answer the question and it seems stackoverflow hides characters surrounded by angle brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The same class described in the accepted answer but overridden **in the Kotlin** and with **AndroidX** imports:

```
import android.util.Pair
import androidx.annotation.MainThread
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import java.util.*

class ExtendedLiveData<T>() : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val observers: MutableList<Pair<LifecycleOwner, Observer<in T>>> = ArrayList()

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        observers.add(Pair(owner, observer))
        super.observe(owner, observer)
    }

    @MainThread
    private fun resetAllObservers() {
        for (observer in observers) {
            super.observe(observer.first, observer.second)
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    private fun removeAllObservers() {
        for (observer in observers) {
            removeObservers(observer.first)
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    fun setValueWithoutNotify(value: T) {
        removeAllObservers()
        super.setValue(value)
        println("Not notifying value " + getValue())
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun removeObserver(observer: Observer<in T>) {
        for (observerItem in observers) {
            if (observerItem.second == observer && observerItem.first.lifecycle
                    .currentState == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED
            ) {
                observers.remove(observerItem)
            }
        }
        super.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    override fun setValue(value: T) {
        super.setValue(value)
        if (!hasObservers()) {
            resetAllObservers()
        }
    }

    fun resetValue() {
        super.setValue(null)
    }

}
```